# 'With rollup' sql error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to write a sql query with grouping and I get the error:- *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.*

The query I am writing is as below:-

```
SELECT          CONTRACT,  
        PACONTNUMBER,  
        Project Manager ID,  
        Status,  
        Project Type,  
        Project Fee Amount,  
        Forecast Total Cost,  
        Forecast Profit,
        Forecast %,
        Actual Billings,
        Actual Total Cost,
        Current Actual Profit,
        Current %,
        GROUPING(PACONTNUMBER) as PACONTNUMBER,  
        SUM(Project Fee Amount) as Project Fee,
        SUM(Forecast Total Cost) as Forecast Cost,
        SUM(Forecast Profit) as Forecast Profit,
        SUM(Forecast %) as Forecast Percentage,
        SUM(Actual Billings) as Billings Total Actual,
        SUM(Actual Total Cost) as Total Cost Actual
FROM        dbo.vwPAProjects_Summary_New_2
GROUP BY   
        CONTRACT,    
        Project Manager ID,  
        Status,  
        Project Type,  
        Project Fee Amount,  
        Forecast Total Cost,  
        Forecast Profit,
        Forecast %,
        Actual Billings,
        Actual Total Cost,
        Current Actual Profit,
        Current %,
        PACONTNUMBER with rollup 
ORDER BY    GROUPING (PACONTNUMBER)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction in trying to get this to work?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have spaces in your identifiers. For SQL Server you can surround then in square brakets `[x]` for example:

```
SELECT          
        CONTRACT,  
        PACONTNUMBER,  
        [Project Manager ID],
        Status,  
        [Project Type],  
        .
        .
        SUM([Actual Total Cost]) as [Total Cost Actual]
FROM        dbo.vwPAProjects_Summary_New_2
GROUP BY   
        CONTRACT,    
        [Project Manager ID],  
        .
        .
        PACONTNUMBER with rollup 
ORDER BY    GROUPING (PACONTNUMBER)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer for inserting square brackets.  this solved that problem but has now thrown up a new one.  When I run the query it highlights an werror that my FROM clause is not a valid column name????  I am obviously not trying to use it as a column name so this has stumped me?

Comment: @user1086159 Ask a new question that has the new query and also post the exact error message you get.